# cross compiling with gyp

Tags: cross-compiling, gyp

Does gyp support cross-compiling? If so are there any instuctions? If not, are there any tricks to get it to do cross compile anyways?

I am trying to use some of the chromium libraries and their build systems depend on gyp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For further reference, here is a possible solution to cross compile. It was taken from [here](https://code.google.com/p/libjingle/issues/detail?id=172#c3)

```
SYSROOT=/build/arm-generic/
CPPPATH=/build/arm-generic/usr/include/
LIBPATH=/build/arm-generic/usr/lib/
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/build/arm-generic/usr/lib/pkgconfig/
AR=armv7a-cros-linux-gnueabi-ar
AS=armv7a-cros-linux-gnueabi-as
LD=armv7a-cros-linux-gnueabi-ld
NM=armv7a-cros-linux-gnueabi-nm
RANLIB=armv7a-cros-linux-gnueabi-ranlib
CC=armv7a-cros-linux-gnueabi-gcc
CXX=armv7a-cros-linux-gnueabi-g++
CPPDEFINES = 'NACL_BUILD_ARCH=arm'
CCFLAGS = '-fPIC'
```

No need to use them all ofc, just select what you need.